# GCC Errors More Readable For Method Signature

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

When GCC raises an error, it shows the method definition with details.

For example, instead of showing:

```
std::string
```

it shows:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
```

Is there any flag, tool, or solution that exists to make the GCC errors more simple? like showing `std::string` instead of the basic signature.

**Note**, I'm looking for a solution for any kind of type and not specifically for `string`.

Comment: That idea is good in almost all cases, but when the error is because `std::string` didn't match some function due to e.g. incompatible allocator template argument, it will make things worse. Not sure how to reconcile that...

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks, I've updated the question about the types (cases) ;)

Comment: @MaxLanghof I completely agree, for that case which you mentioned, then we can disable the flag or not using the tool which made the compile result more simple.

Comment: I mean, you can pipe your command line output through something that replaces all occurrences of the long form with `std::string` (similar for any other template long-form of your choosing). But IDE integration might be more difficult...

Comment: @MaxLanghof it would be awesome, thanks ;)